# Is Android SharedPreferences and IOS keychain used for App ever auto deleted by system?

Tags: android, ios, sharedpreferences, keychain, capacitor-plugin

In Capacitor 3, I am using [capacitor-secure-storage-plugin](https://github.com/martinkasa/capacitor-secure-storage-plugin). I want to store some important data using this and my concern is whether this storage can be automatically cleared by the OS system.

For Android, this plugin uses AndroidKeyStore and SharedPreferences and for IOS it uses keychain wrapper (as per their documentation).

I know users can clear the app data from setting but that's fine because the user is also logged out (firebase authentication) when data is cleaned manually.

Comment: SharedPreferences are deleted by the System only when either the data is cleared or the app is uninstalled by the user.

Comment: @AlphaOne, when you say "deleted by the System only when either the data is cleared", do you mean data is cleared manually by a user? I just wanna make user that the system is not deleting it automatically.

Comment: yes, manually by the user